# Check if textbox is empty, and if it is empty I want plugin from bootstrap, to popover but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying here to check whether the input text box is empty or not. And if it is empty I want plugin from bootstrap to popover but it's not working. I tired it a lot times but it either gives other values.

```
$("input").blur(function() {

    var check =$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
                check.each(function(){
                    if (check.value==""){

                         check.popover();
                         end();
                 }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by empty? not checked?

Comment: how many checkboxes are in the `tr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do:

```
var check =$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
    check.each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val() ) =="" ){
            $(this).popover();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `check` variable inside your `each`, but that variable is still a reference to the entire set of inputs. You want to check `this.value`, which will be a reference to the element at the current step in the iteration (and similarly, `$(this).popover()`).

Answer (score 0):

While working out i got all i needed was .Following code worked out anyways thanks for all the people who tried out and that made me closer to the answer.

```
$("input").blur(function() {

    var check =$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
                check.each(function(){
                    if (this.value==""){
                    $(this).popover({
                        html: true,
                        trigger: 'blur',
                        content: function() {
                            return 'Invalid Time';

                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
});
```